# How to cast a object into another?

Tags: java, api, events, plugins, reflection

First off, if the question is worded wrong. Let me know, I wasn't sure how to word this question. ^^'

Ok, right now, I am working on a plugin API so people can change the programs behavior without having to modify the source, and users who can not program, but still want to modify it, can download other plugins people have made already.
And right now, I am currently working on the Event System, where if a event is fired, the plugin can detect that a react to it. And I want the user to be able to put this code:

```
handleEvent(Event e) {}
```

And then use:

```
if(e instanceof <EVENTTYPE>) {
    <EVENTTYPE> e2 = (<EVENTTYPE>) e;
    // Do code here that could not be normally accessible without casting
}
```

But I have no idea how to do this, so I have no code to show. But, if you want the code I do have which works fine (Except for this, which I said I have no idea how to do) I can give it to you.

Comment: Note that you can't cast objects, only references (and primitives).

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to implement an event mechanism?

Comment: No, I have that working already, I meant I want to make it so if a plugin is listening for the main Event class itself, and not a specific one, make it so when the PluginManager throws it to all the plugins listening, I can make it so the plugin can use the code above and cast the Main event object to a certain event if that is the one that was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclasses of any class can add extra methods to the original class. If an object whose type is that subclass is reference by a variable whose type is the superclass, those extra methods won't be visible because the type of the variable does not know about them. For the extra methods to become available, the object needs to be assigned to a variable of the correct type, and that requires a downcast. That's what's happening in your example.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I am using reflection, because this is a API that is used by plugins on my software to extend it, not a API that other softwares use in order extend themselves. I was asking how I would make it so when my software fires a event for the plugins to react to, if the event has subclasses, users can cast it to it and then use functions that would normally be not accessible unless listening to that specifically. But, thank you for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you were asking

Comment: Its ok, I do that a lot in the real life world :D

Comment: And on stack overflow